# static library is missing on other computer

Tags: static-libraries, wininet, ftp-server

I have written program that sends files to ftp server. In my computer, where I have VC++ 2008 express edition, it works fine, but when I tried it on the others computers it hadn't worked. I figured out that my program can't connect to ftp server and the code line #pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib") in my code is suspicious for me. It's the only static library that I have included be myself. How can I fix this problem? If there are any other ways to work with ftp server without wininet.h library commands then I'm glad to know.

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting on connect? Is this a firewall problem because the local firewall on the other computer is configured differently? The use of `wininet.lib` is unlikely to be the problem here.